# How does cookie expiration work under IIS7 and ASP.NET, and is there a way to auto refresh it? Domain level cookie expiration?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iis-7

I'm using a single login page that uses form authentication.  This page creates a domain cookie on mysites.com.

I have three other websites which require the authentication to access.  In my page loginsso.mysites.com I have my cookie expiration set to 30 minutes.  However what happens is when that cookie expires it will kick the users out of my other three sites.

To make this more complicated each of those 3 sites has an idle time out.

So this is how it works:

The user logs into mysso.mysite.com

it creates a domain level cookie (this cookie has a 30 minute timeout expiration)

-mysitea.mysite.com has a 3 idle  hour expiration

-mysiteb.mysite.com has a 1 idle hour expiration

-mysitec.mysite.com has a 2 idle  hour expiration

So the user who's logged into mysso.mysite.com and navigates over to mysiteb.mysite.com and is working there for 30 minutes will no longer be able to access the site after 30 because of the cookie specifications on mysso.mysite.com.

Basically I need a way to handle this.  If a user navigates to mysiteb and works he's not idle and should not be kicked out of mysitesso.

Hope this makes any sense.

It's also possible I am mixing SessionTimeOut with CookieExperation and how they are handled.

Comment: Why don't you make your individual sites look for the domain cookie and validate it, instead of maintaining their own cookies?

Comment: @likeitlikeit Okay but what keeps the cookie from expiring in 30 minutes?

Comment: @likeitlikeit and what do you mean by validating it?  They do validate it, those individual sites will allow the domain cookie ot log you in

Comment: Basically, you set a cookie at a given time, and give it an expiration time. Usually, applications just re-set it with every request and handle the authentication in a session associated with that cookie. I would strongly discourage doing authentication with a cookie only, because if somebody manages to steal that cookie, he will be able to access your sites without proper credentials.

Comment: @likeitlikeit I dont handle auth with cookie only, you have to have Ldap first and then have a user in the database.  Also, you say re-set it with every request, i was under the impression that only Sessions get updated with every request and cookie experation was just a set time

Comment: In that case, you should be able to make use of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992279/1553481).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, use a session cookie for both the SSO and the individual applications. A session cookie is a cookie that doesn't have an expiration date set – it will stay around until the browser is closed (for details, see [here](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=41)). Handle session expiration for all the applications in server-side logic, and destroy the session when a timeout occurs.

You should also make sure that the session cookie is protected from javascript access to prevent XHR attacks (which works in all modern browsers). You can do this like here:

```
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
```

More documentation about the `HttpOnly` attribute can be found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx), or an [in-depth article about form authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) by looking for `HttpOnly`.